# Tool to insert tags (e.g., #journal) into a markdown file?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

*nvUltra* and *Obsidian*'s Dataview plugin have gotten me interested in tagging my markdown files.  For example I have 298 journal entries written in markdown, most of which do not have tags. I would like to be able to add tags to groups of these files. For example, I'd like to add a *#journal* tag to each one or *#travel* to a selected subset.  Such a tool would also make *nvUltra* more useful to me since I have many additional markdown files.

Do any of you know of a tool to accomplish this task?

Thanks!